# async await utility function synchronization?

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

If we define a utility function like this:

```
/**
 * Delete the entire database
 */
export async function deleteDatabase(db) {
  await db.delete()
}
```

And we call it.

```
deleteDatabase(db)
nextFunction()
```

Then next function will not be called before the `db.delete()` has completed correct?

I think this is how it works, so I just want to confirm the semantics.

### DexieJS Demo

Incorporating the answers into this DexieJS Demo for those interested in the actual use case:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-dexie-one-to-many

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
deleteDatabase(db)
```

This expression returns with promise immediately.

So `nextFunction()` will be called before the db.delete() has completed

You should await for `deleteDatabase(db)` as well

Answer (score 7):

"Then next function will not be called before the `db.delete()` has completed correct?" Wrong. It will be called **BEFORE** async operation has completed.

```js
const delay = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms))

async function deleteDatabase() {
  console.log('Deleting DB')
  await delay(1000)
  console.log('DB deleted')
}

function nextFunction() {
  console.log('Next function')
}

deleteDatabase()
nextFunction()
```

You need to have another `async/await` wrapper function or use `.then` to chain promises

```
deleteDatabase().then(nextFunction)
```

Comment: Thanks - Great Answer!  Normally I would accept this one, but we have a new contributor, and he needs some points, so I will accept his.  Hope that's ok.

Comment: What happens if deleteDatabase takes longer than 1000ms?

Comment: @Ole that's a strange reasoning, especially since the new contributor doesn't give you the solution (as probably, you are in a non async scope in his answer, so the handling using `then` is more appropriate than suggesting the await)

Comment: @steadweb Why does it matter?  I don't recommend to wait for some random time for task to complete. It was just an example of async task. :)

Comment: Yeah I understand that, but if you're not bothered about the specific task and just want to "fire and forget" there is no point delaying. Delaying suggests you're waiting for the operation to complete, i.e. in a syncrounous manner, and if that fails, it's a false premise delaying :)

Comment: @steadweb Hmmm, not sure I understand you. I did need some async operation to demonstrate that it won't wait for the task to complete. But whatever...

Comment: Of course, apologies, that's the example here, asserting the operation will happen on the next tick. I should learn to read :D Great work :)

Answer (score 2):

If they're in a async context, the next function won't be called, **only if** you put the await before the deleteDatabase

Like this:

```
async myFunc(db) {
    await deleteDatabase(db)
    nextFunction()
}
```

Or even:

```
async myFunc(db) {
    return deleteDatabase(db)
        .then(() => 
            nextFunction()
        )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you call it like

```
deleteDatabase(db)
nextFunction()
```

The next function will be called immediately as you are not awaiting it.

You need to await

```
await deleteDatabase(db)
nextFunction()
```